# Dataform doesn't recognize observablle collection item

Tags: c#, silverlight

I do have a dataform which items source is set from code behind.
The data from which is binded to the dataform is from a observableCollection;

When setting the ItemSource like this, the dataform's add/remove buttons are disabled.

```
dataForm.ItemSource = obsColl.Where(d=>d.id == 2);
```

But when doing this(making a new observable collection only for the selected entity), and setting the item source to the dataform , the buttons are enabled.

```
ObservableCollection<entity> o = new ObserableCollection<entity>(grid.SelectedItem as enity);   
dataform.ItemSource =o;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Does `obsColl.Where(d=>d.id == 2);` returns any value?

Comment: Bahman_Aries - yes it does.

Comment: Could you provide more code to show your data-bindings and how you defined `obsColl`?

Comment: Ahh sorry , I posted a wrong question ( really tired ) , the problem was about the command buttons not the data shown . my question was updated. Sorry for misleading.